# Is the cyclic group: {$\ 1, a, a^2, ... a^{n-1}$} even a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The cyclic group {$\ 1, a, a^2, ... a^{n-1}$} doesn't seem to be a group to me?

For example if it's something like  {$\ 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128$}

then $\ 64*32=2048$, which doesn't belong in the group, hence the closure law is violated.

It might be seem silly but I need help.

Comment: It's congruence.

Comment: Every group depend of its binary operation. So, even $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ could not be a group if you use the incorrect binary operation. So, remember to be aware of the rules of your context, here is really important to take congruence mod $n$ in the exponents.

Comment: What is the context? What is $a$? Where does it live?

Comment: You have to assume $a^n=1$.  The operation is not ordinary multiplication over the integers.

Comment: $a$ is not a number but an abstract symbol. Multiplication here isn't multiplication of real numbers, but an abstract group operation that satisfies $a^n=1$. You can't treat $a$ as a variable and substitute in any number you like. But you can, for example, take $a$ to be a primitive nth root of unity (and the group operation to be multiplication of complex numbers).

Comment: At the moment you have specified only a set. Even if multiplication is implied as the relevant binary operation, you need the relation $a^n=1$ to make this a cyclic group of order $n$ (Again with the implied condition that no lower positive integer power of $a$ is equal to $1$). If you had $a^2=1$ instead some of the elements in your set would be equal, and you'd have the cyclic group of order $2$.

Comment: Both of the two last comment explain the whole story. I am asking you: If you write that set of powers of $a$ be a cyclic group so what are you looking for then? That set is a cyclic group generated by symbol $a$ when we have a relation like $a^n=1$. What is the operation for your second set? Multiplication?

Comment: @DanielMroz Can you please post that as an answer, not as a comment? I don't know why you posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posted my comment as an answer;

$a$ is not a number but an abstract symbol. Multiplication here isn't multiplication of real numbers, but an abstract group operation that satisfies $a^n=1$. 
You can't treat $a$ as a variable and substitute in any number you like. But you can, for example, take $a$ to be a primitive nth root of unity (and the group operation to be multiplication of complex numbers).

Comment: Thanks, I now understand.

Answer (score 3):

A set is or isn't a group under a given binary operation. The most obvious choice for which the given set is a group is $a^i\otimes a^j:=a^{i+j(\operatorname{mod}\, n)}$. In fact, this is an Abelian group, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\backslash n\mathbb{Z}$.